# How to make value in sql a whole string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to generate an insert statement for SQL, to fill a table with the URL key with it's value from the dict
My Jsondata looks like this:

```
dict_items([('date', '20122013-10-15'), ('termijn', 1), ('spreker', 'Van der Burg'), 
('rol', 'Mevrouw'), ('indegree', 2), ('aantal_interrupts', 6), ('interruptors', 
{'Thieme': 2, 'Pechtold': 4}), ('OnderwerpDebat', 'Begroting Algemene Zaken en begroting van de Koning'), 
('url', 'https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/h-tk-20122013-10-15.xml')])
```

```
for index in range(len(jsondata)):
    for key, value in jsondata[index].items():
        if key == 'url':
            columns = key
            values = value
            sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s );" % ('onderwerp', columns, values)
            print(sql)
            cursor.execute(sql)

cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM onderwerp; """).fetchall()
```

The output of the print statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO onderwerp ( url ) VALUES ( https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/h-tk-20122013-10-15.xml );
```

What I want the output to be is:

```
INSERT INTO onderwerp ( url ) VALUES ( "https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/h-tk-20122013-10-15.xml" );
```

Whenever I want to perform the execute it says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-1e0bc150168a> in <module>
      9             sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s );" % ('onderwerp', key, str(value))
     10             print(sql)
---> 11             cursor.execute(sql)
     12 
     13 cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM onderwerp; """).fetchall()

OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"
```

So this means the URL hasn't been saved as a whole string but rather as a combination of characters. How do I get to that point?

Comment: you will need to wrap it in quotes then so `VALUES ( %s )` would need to be `VALUES ( \"%s\" )`. However sql injection attacks have been around for decades you would be much better to use parameterised sqls with bind parameters instead of direct sql

Comment: https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/ explains how to and the benfits of parameterized statments.

Comment: Oke so I was able to solve my problem. The constraints for my table where that the Url datatype was VARCHAR(), but I didn't specify a maximum length for VARCHAR so it set it automatically to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Oke so I was able to solve my problem. The constraints for my table where that the Url datatype was VARCHAR(), but I didn't specify a maximum length for VARCHAR so it set it automatically to 1.